# Pygame Slow refresh rate

Tags: python, pygame

I have created Pygame, which has objects (balls) which randomly move around the screen and the mouse control a character which the user moves around to avoid the other objects. but the random ball that move around the screen have slow refresh rate (you can see them flashing while moving).

I don't know which part of the code is to blame, the objects that move around are loaded here:

```
ballpic = pygame.image.load('ball.png').convert_alpha()
```

I don't which other part of the game is to blame so I can include in question, so I have created a pastebin http://pastebin.com/H6KkTvZU which has the game code (short game).

Thank you

Comment: It's missing resources, like `bg.jpg`.  pygame.error: Couldn't open bg.jpg

Comment: `backdrop = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg').convert_alpha()`
`menu = pygame.image.load('green.jpg').convert_alpha()`
`ballpic = pygame.image.load('ball.png').convert_alpha()`
`mouseball = pygame.image.load('mouseball.gif').convert_alpha()`

Comment: @jgritty I'm following what your saying sorry ?

Comment: Can you post the image resource files somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `display.update()` on every iteration of  `for i in range(enemies)` loop.
Try doing it once per frame, after you have `blit`ted all the sprites.

Even better, learn how to use `display.flip()` properly; it's faster if you update large portions of the screen.

Comment: Your right it was the display.update() that caused the the issue, cheers mate

Answer (score 2):

The [Pygame newbie tutorial](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/newbieguide.html) has some other useful advice, particularly how to use "Dirty rect animation" if your frame-rate is still too low.